# Adding plugins to WolfCMS

Tags: php, content-management-system, xampp

I'm running a copy of WolfCMS locally with xampp and have the need to add a new plugin. I've added the required code to index, everything is there that is required, now I just need to get into the admin page and set the plugin to active. Unfortunately, on my local version the admin page isn't displaying the list of plugins.

I know the backend isn't broken because the live version of the site works fine and I copied everything from it. Everything else is working fine, frontend and backend.

If anyone is familiar with Wolf and running it locally and could suggest any ideas why it's doing this I would be very grateful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the link to the new page. The site is set to use short URLs, www.mysite.com/admin/?/page and i didn't have the question mark in the link i was using.

Very odd, and asinine, but it works now